# Cannot find Tiny OS source-code Repository

Tags: svn, tinyos

> I cannot find **Tiny-OS source-code's** *repository* **link** on **SVN**
>   Please help thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the **git** repository: https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main

they use [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), <s>which is not compatible with any svn client you might have</s>

**UPDATE 1:**
actually i was able to check it out via SVN with this URL https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main

Comment: Thanx for ur concers...i have an assignment, which state I only have to download from an SVN repository...

Comment: see my update answer, actually SVN works on github. I did not know that.

Comment: mean can i download github's repository from SVN client ?

Comment: yes, you can use the checkout or export feature of your svn client.

Comment: you're welcome, please accept my answer. that's how stackoverflow works: http://stackoverflow.com/tour